# Question regarding Webdriver driver = new ChromeDriver() methods

Tags: selenium-webdriver

**Question**

When we are using

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

driver object will show methods of only WebDriver interface or ChromeDriver methods plus extra methods created in RC, Chromium or Chrome?

To understand I did some homework let me know where I went wrong.

Inside Package

1. Interface - SuperInterface
2. Interface - ChildSuperInterface extends SuperInterface
3. Class - SuperClass implements ChildSuperInterface
4. Class - ChildSuperClass extends SuperClass

I created some extra methods in `ChildSuperclass`

**Now** 
When I have created a separate class name `WorkOnClass` and create object driver1 in it. driver1 shows only methods of interface `ChildSuperInterface`. Not showing extra methods created in parent or child class SuperClass and ChildSuperClass.

```
ChildSuperInterface driver1 = new ChildSuperClass();
```

Need more understanding of this if you can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to be a basic OOP question, not actually specific to QA or testing at all.

Answer (score 1):

When you define your driver as

```java
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

using reference `driver`you will be able to access only the methods which are defined in `WebDriver` and implemented in `ChromeDriver`.

> Basically, in Java **you can access the objects through the references of parent types** because those child objects inherit what is publicly accessible in parents. But **you will not be able to access parent object using reference of child type** because parent objects do not have methods descibed in child types.

You will still be able to access `ChromeDriver` specific methods if you cast your driver. For example:

```java
((ChromeDriver)driver).chromeDriverSepcificMethod();
```

Comment: If you find yourself using `((ChromeDriver)driver)` you should just convert the initial definition to `ChromeDriver driver`, otherwise it's too easy to later on switch that definition and not find out you just broke something until runtime.

Comment: True but not completely. You might not be aware of what particular implementation is under your `WebDriver`. Your framework might support many. So it might happen that somewhere in your framework you test your instance for if it is `ChromeDriver` or `FirefoxDriver` and then invoke some specific method on that.

Comment: I don't think we disagree, so perhaps I didn't express myself clearly. My point is that if you have `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver()` and later on `((ChromeDriver)driver).specificMethod()`, then if you change the initial definition to e.g. `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver()` the compiler can't tell you `.specificMethod` will be a NPE. Instead if you have `ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver()` and `driver.specificMethod()`, then if you change the definition to `FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver()` (or even `WebDriver driver = `), the compiler errors on `.specificMethod`.

Comment: You're right that if you explicitly test then cast, that's OK, but that detail isn't in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
ChildSuperInterface driver1 = new ChildSuperClass();
```

Tells that driver1 is of type **ChildSuperInterface** , so it will have only the methods in the class :  `Interface - ChildSuperInterface extends SuperInterface`.

it won't have the inherited methods, from **SuperInterface**

it won't have methods from any other subclasses as its not inherited yet when seen from **ChildSuperInterface**

If you want all the methods then you should give the type as `SuperClass`

```
SuperClass driver1 = new ChildSuperClass();
```

in this case it will have all the child methods and inherited methods

You should check access modifiers also:

[image]

**In case of webdriver:**

Webdriver looks like

```
chromedriver implements webdriver
```

so if you mentions

```
chromedriver driver;
```

It will have only methods from chromedriver class and no methods from webdriver interface.

```
webdriver driver;
```

will have both chromedriver and webdriver methods

Answer (score 0):

`ChromeDriver` is an implementation of `WebDriver` interface, thus it must implement all the methods defined in the interface. If you instantiate a `WebDriver` object using `WebDriver` interface you get access to the methods defined in the interface only.

This is a basic example of composition.